# Dell Vostro 1550 and Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: dell

I have just got this new dell vostro 1550 ci3 today(16th april 2012) with ubuntu 10.10 in it. As this version is going to be outdated at end of april.

Is it advisable to install 12.04 over this machine? or the warranty will be void if there is new installation of linux on this machine? What to do? Upgrade or keep the version for next 6 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is [Ubuntu Certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201105-8077), which means regardless of the software that runs on it, the firmware has been hardened to "just work" on Linux, which is the most important part of the hardware enablement work. Looking at the parts list, I don't see anything exceptional that you would have a problem with. As with all upgrades, ensure that you have a backup of your most critical information before proceeding. Also, regarding your BIOS, if it's working fine, please please don't change it :). It would be really helpful if you ran the [Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/) suite to let us know how your platform is doing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was nervous To upgrade because I had bad experience with HP as the customer support made questions when i downgraded to Xp on that machine. So it seems dell is doing good job. Thanks again. I'll test with ubuntu friendly and will pass on the test.